# How to make ActivityResult output to 2 different textview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to make a speech to text application but output on a different text view. I tried to search the solution on the internet, but most of the answers they only output to 1 text view. I want to make it look like this:

Here is the image of my idea: https://i.stack.imgur.com/orTec.png

This is for study purposes. I hope someone can help me

```
    TextView textview1, textview2;
    Button btnVoice1, btnVoice2;

    textview1= findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    textview2= findViewById(R.id.textview2);

    btnVoice1 = findViewById(R.id.btnVoice1);
    btnVoice2 = findViewById(R.id.btnVoice2);

    btnVoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startVoiceInput();
        }
    });

    btnVoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startVoiceInput();
        }
    });
```

//Function

```
    private void startVoiceInput(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, 
    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say Something!");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                textview1.setText(result.get(0));
                // how to make textview2 output when btnVoice2 is click
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Dont use same **REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT** for  startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT).After this,inside **onActivityResult**,you can use different requestCode using switch case,

Comment: @Kabir Thank you so much

Comment: i'm going to post an answer now

Comment: do you still need an answer though ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes please, if you can give me the best and simplify version

Answer (score 0):

**For Multiple onActivityResult for single Activity change your code like this:**

```
    int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT=100;
    int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT_SECOND=101;
    TextView textview1, textview2;

        Button btnVoice1, btnVoice2;

        textview1= findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        textview2= findViewById(R.id.textview2);

        btnVoice1 = findViewById(R.id.btnVoice1);
        btnVoice2 = findViewById(R.id.btnVoice2);

        btnVoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startVoiceInput(REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
            }
        });

        btnVoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startVoiceInput(REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT_SECOND);
            }
        });


    private void startVoiceInput(int code){
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, 
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say Something!");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, code);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {

            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    textview1.setText(result.get(0));

                }
                break;
            }
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT_SECOND:{
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    textview2.setText(result.get(0));

                }
                break;
            }


        }
    }
```